# Docker initialization on OSX: is a dial error normal?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I ran boot2docker for the first time. At the end of the `/usr/local/bin/boot2docker up` process, I got the following:

```
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.19/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
bash-4.3$
```

Do I worry?

Comment: Just in case: did you try a `boot2docker delete` and `boot2docker init` again?

Comment: Actually, what I tried was just using docker, and so far it has worked fine. It only printed that message once in the purple 'boot' window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That indicates that something is wrong.

The "dial unix..." error is saying that the `docker` executable is failing to connect. You'll mostly get this if the VM isn't running or isn't configured correctly. In this case, it looks like the `docker` service on the VM had some problem and the error is coming from inside the VM (that's why it's `/var/run/docker.sock` instead of an https connection to the VM).

It's not possible to diagnose without more logs, but I recommend [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) as the new replacement for boot2docker. (It still runs the boot2doocker distro, but it's a little more sophisticated at setting up the VM.)